# Extract data with an OLE DB faster

Tags: ssis, oledb, extract

Hi everyone I'm trying to extract a lot of records from a lot of joined tables and views using SSIS (OLE DB SOURCE) but it takes a huge time! the problem is due to the query because when I parsed it on sql server it takes more than hour ! Her's my ssis package design

[image]

I thought of paralleled extraction using two OLE DB source and merge join but it isn't recommended using it! besides it takes more time! Is there any way to help me please?

Comment: You need to describe your problem more clearly. 500000 data (I assume records you mean) is a really small number in general. How many tables? Try to come up with a representative problem statement with some sort of table structure and data. Then the folks on this site will be able to help you in a more concrete manner, otherwise every suggestion would merely be a shot in the dark.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question in the current form. In addition to what Anoop has stated, also post the execution plan. SSIS will not be able to move data any faster than the source system can feed data.

Answer (score 3):

Writing the `T-sql` query with all the `joins` in the `OLEDB source` will always be faster than using `different source` and then using `Merge Join` IMHO. The reason is SSIS is `memory Oriented architecture` .It has to bring all the data from `N` different tables into its buffers and then filter it using Merge join and more over Merge Join is an [asynchronous](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx) component(Semi Blocking) therefore it cannot use the same input buffer for its output .A new buffer is created and you may run out of memory if there are large number of rows extracted from the table.

Having said that there are few ways you can enhance the extraction performance using OLEDB source

1.Tune your SQL Query .Avoid using `Select *`

2.Check network bandwidth .You just cannot have faster throughput than your bandwidth supports.

3.All source adapters are asynchronous .[The speed of an SSIS Source is not about how fast your query runs](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/02/17/the-ssis-tuning-tip-that-everyone-misses.aspx) .It's about how fast the data is retrieved .

As others have suggested above ,you should show us the query and also the time it is taking to retireve the data else these are just few optimization technique which can make the extraction faster

Comment: Yes only needed data are selected ! the problem is due to the query it takes more than 1 hour because there's a lot of conditions and columns

Comment: So for that you need to show us your `query` along with other information such as `execution plan` , `ssis package design` . We can't help you if you simply say that your query is taking time to execute

Comment: I added the ssis package design to my question but the query takes 5 pages !

Comment: A while ago for one of my clients, I had a situation where the queries were tor·tur·ous·ly long and it used to take about 50 minutes to process the data. After s.o.m.e effort, I was able to bring it down to 4-5 minutes. if you are using any kind of aggregation (sum, min, max etc), see if you can have a separate table to store them and join them to the main query. Are you using too many cte's? Maybe put them in temp tables with appropriate indexes. Can you do some portion of those temps in parallel as separate tasks and then glue them together by querying those table?

Comment: As also stated by Praveen: I strongly suggest you simply write one SQL query rather in your source rather than trying to build a SQL query in SSIS. It will likely be a lot faster. But you need to post more info if you want help.

Comment: AnoopVerma No I haven't any kind of aggregation on the main query 
@ElectricLIama I've already posted some additional info here : 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357336/performance-in-an-ssis-package-with-asynchronous-component?noredirect=1#comment23437508_16357336)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting a screen shot of your data flow. I doubt whether the slowness you encounter is truly the fault of the `OLE DB Source` component.

Instead, you have 3 asynchronous components that result in a 2 full blocks of your data flow and one that's partially blocking (AGG, SRT, MRJ). That first aggregate will have to wait for all 500k rows to arrive before it can finish the aggregate and *then* pass it along to the sort.

These transformations also result in fragmented memory. Normally, a memory buffer is filled with data and visits each component in a data flow. Any changes happen directly to that address space and the engine can parallelize operations if it can determine step 2 is modifying field X and step 3 is modifying Y. The [async components](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx) are going to cause data to be copied from one space to another. This is a double slow down. The first is the physical act of copying data from address space 0x01 to 0xFA or something. The second is that it reduces the available amount of memory for the dtexec process. No longer can SSIS play with all N gigs of memory. Instead, you'll have quartered your memory and after each async is done, that memory partition is just left there until the data flow completes.

If you want this run better, you'll need to fix your query. It may result in your aggregated data being materialized into a staging table or all in one big honkin' query.

Open a new question and provide insight into the data structures, indexes, data volumes, the query itself and preferably the query plan - estimated or actual. If you need help identifying these things, there are plenty of helpful folks here that can help you through the process.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's pretty helping ! Actually asynchronous components are used to eliminate duplicate rows I found another way using Lookup and sql query 
http://blog.homsys.com/trucs-astuces/la-gestion-des-doublons-avec-ssis
but it doesn't work because I need to select from data extracted with OLE DB SRC not from my data base ! is there anyway to help me ?

Comment: @unknown Where did you get this information from `asynchronous components are used to eliminate duplicate rows ` ? It will be better if you post it as a new question citing ur requirement and what have you tried

Comment: I mean the components (MLT, AGG, SRT, MRJ) are used to eliminate them ! and it works for sure

Comment: @praveen her's a link to my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357336/performance-in-an-ssis-package-with-asynchronous-component