# Performance in an SSIS package with asynchronous component

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis

Hi everyone as I already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335664/extract-data-with-an-ole-db-faster/16351447?noredirect=1#comment23430645_16351447) :

I face some problems excuting my SSIS packages, actually they take huge time. Due to a lot of constraints I'm trying to resolve one to one ! I start with the query it takes more than three hours to extract 720 000 rows her's it:

```
Select 
    --11 fields from tbl1
    Tbl1.field1 As field1,
    ….
    .
    .
    Tbl1.field11 As field11,

    CASE WHEN (dbo.tbl1.field11 = 'J') 
                          THEN N'Batch' ELSE dbo.tbl1.field11 END AS creation_oprid, CONVERT(date, tbl1.date1) 
                          AS creation_date, CONVERT(date, tbl1.date2) AS update_date, 
                          CASE WHEN (dbo.tbl1.field12 = 'J') 
                          THEN N'Batch' ELSE dbo.tbl1.field12 END AS update_oprid, 
    tbl1.id, 

    --3 fields from tbl2

    Tbl2.field1 As field1,
    ….
    .
    .
    Tbl2.field3 As field3,

    Tbl3.field1 As field1,
    Tbl4.field1 As field1,
    Tbl3_2.field1 As field1,

    --30 fields from tbl5
    Tbl5.field1 As field1,
    ….
    .
    .
    Tbl5.field30 As field30,

    --7 fields from tbl6

    Tbl6.field1 As field1,
    ….
    .
    .
    Tbl6.field7 As field7,

    --5 fields from tbl7

    Tbl7.field1 As field1,
    ….
    .
    .
    Tbl8.field5 As field5,


    --7 fields from tbl8

    Tbl8.field1 As field1,
    ….
    .
    .
    Tbl8.field7 As field7,

    --

    ---6 conditions from the same table and the same field and 6 conditions with AND

      CASE WHEN tbl9.field1 = N'Value1' THEN tbl9.field2 END AS XXX1,
      CASE WHEN tbl9.field1 = N'Value1' THEN tbl9.field2 AND
      Tbl9.field3= 'SAMEValue' THEN N'Batch' ELSE Tbl9.field3 END AS YYY1,

    .
    .
      CASE WHEN tbl9.field1 = N'Value6' THEN tbl9.field2 END AS XXX6,
      CASE WHEN tbl9.field1 = N'Value6' THEN tbl9.field2 AND
      Tbl9.field3= 'SAMEValue' THEN N'Batch' ELSE Tbl9.field3 END AS YYY6,

    Tbl3_4.field1 As field1,
    Dbo.tbl10.field1 As field1,
    Dbo.tbl10_1.field1 As field1,


    CASE WHEN dbo.tbl8.TYPE_ID = 9 THEN N'Y' WHEN dbo. dbo.tbl8.TYPE_ID = 10 THEN N'N' END AS
                           flag, 
    CASE WHEN dbo.tbl11.field_ID IS NOT NULL 
                          THEN ('O_' + dbo.tbl11.field_ID) END AS field_ID, 
    CASE WHEN dbo.tbl12.field_ID IS NOT NULL THEN ('L_' + dbo.tbl12.field_ID) END AS field_ID
                        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id,dbo.tbl8.FIELDID,dbo.tbl8.Field2ID) AS RowNumber



    FROM         
    dbo.tbl1 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl8 
        ON tbl1.field_ID = Tbl8.contact_field_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl12 
        ON dbo.TBL1.PERSON_ID = dbo.tbl12.FIELD_ID_CONTACT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PS_RSF_OPP_CONTACT 
        ON dbo.TBL1.PERSON_ID = dbo.tbl11.FIELD_ID_CONTACT 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl3 AS tbl3_4 
        ON TBL1.COMM_METHOD = tbl3_4.FIELDVALUE AND (FIELDNAME = N'VALUE') AND (EFF_STATUS = N'A') 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl9 
        ON TBL1.FIELD_ID = tbl9.FIELD_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl5 
        ON TBL1.FIELD_ID = tbl5.FIELD_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl7 
        ON TBL1.FIELD_ID = tbl7.FIELD_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl6
        ON TBL1.FIELD_ID = tbl6.FIELD_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl10 AS tbl10_1 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl13 
        ON tbl10_1.CM_PURPOSE_TYPE_ID = dbo.tbl13.CM_PURPOSE_TYPE_ID 
        ON TBL1.FIELD_ID = tbl13.FIELD_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl10 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl14 
        ON dbo.tbl10.CM_PURPOSE_TYPE_ID = dbo.tbl14.CM_PURPOSE_TYPE_ID 
        ON TBL1.FIELD_ID = tbl14.FIELD_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl3 AS tbl3_2 
        ON TBL1.PRSN_TYPE = tbl3_2.FIELDVALUE AND (tbl3_2.FIELDNAME =          N'PRSN_TYPE') 
        AND (tbl3_2.EFF_STATUS = N'A') 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl4 
        ON TBL1.FIELD_CD = TBL4.FIELD_CD 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl3 AS tbl3 
        ON TBL1.Field_CD = tbl3.FIELDVALUE AND (tbl3.FIELDNAME = N' LANG') 
        AND (tbl3.EFF_STATUS = N'A') 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl2 AS tbl2 
        ON TBL1.FIELD_ID = tbl2.FIELD_ID AND (tbl2.PRIMARY_IND = 'Y')
    ORDER BY dbo.TBL1.PERSON_ID
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Do u have index defined on your foreign key columns ?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, put your query in there and hit Ctrl-L. This will generate the Estimated Execution Plan. Save that plan out as something like LongRunning.sqlplan Download [SQL Sentry's Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) It's free. Open the .sqlplan with PE and click the "Anonymize" button. Post that screenshot somewhere or upload it to sqlperformance.com and link back to it here. Finally, could you explain what your end goal is. Your other question said you were eliminating duplicates, could you explain dedupe logic?

Comment: @praveen I haven't any integrity constraints.
billinkc Well my objectif is to improve performance of this package. But before loading data duplicate rows must be eliminated. 
So we generate ROW_NUMBER()in order to have the duplicate row at the beginning. then we duplicate the flow using (Mult). After we use aggregation I apply min to row_number and group by to id, tbl8.FIELDID & tbl8.Field2ID and we sort them. Finally, we use inner join to deduplicate rows.

Comment: @billinkc I'm not able to insall SQL Sentry's Plan Explorer I haven't enough space on my PC ! but I found a solution using sql query to eliminate duplicate rows so it takes less time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi @billinkc I need to install [SQL Sentry's Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) but It requires .Net 4.0, I didn't rich to install it. I've .Net 3.5 installed it couldn't help ?